# .aar file is not available after convert app into library

Tags: android, aar

i want to convert app into library module, i have follow the steps of Convert an app module to a library module
https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

it syncs and builds successfully. i am not able to know is it converted into library module(because not able to find library file) or if it is converted then where is the location and how can i include that??

Comment: if build sucessfully than  Please check  \app\build\outputs\aar

Comment: thank's, @Redman,@Pratik18 now i got two files app-debug.aar and app-release.aar.